# I can't understand how the time complexity will be calculated in these 2 cases

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Here is the first algorithm. It is not in any proper syntax:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
       for(k=1;k<=100;k++)
        {printf("hello")
         }
        }
      }
```

In this case we calculate the time complexity as O(n^2) by seeing the total number of times the printf statement will be executed. So, we add the number of times the k loop will run for each i from 1 to n.

2nd code:

```
{int n=(2)^(2)^k //read as 2 to the power 2 to the power k
 for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {j=2
  while(j<=n)
  {j=j^2
   printf("hello")
  }
 }
}
```

Here we get the time complexity as O(n(loglogn)). We see that the nth loop will be executed n(k+1) times. We substituted the value of k and got the time complexity.

I dont understand why we didn't add the total number of times the print statement got executed to calculate the time complexity in the 2nd code like we did in the first code. We only saw how many times it runs in the nth loop to calculate the answer.

Comment: feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your basics. The time complexity of first loop is **O(N^2)** and its totally unrelated to `printf` statement. Its about the **total number of iterations of you innermost loop**.

Your innermost loop in `code 1` runs `100*(N^2)` which is **O(N^2)** , the answer would remain the same even when your code 1 is:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
       for(k=1;k<=100;k++)
        {
         }
        }
      }
```

So, as long as your innermost loop has no statement or statement that takes **O(1)** time, the answer remains the same.

For you second code: while loop always runs `log(logn)` times and outer loop always runs `n` times , therefore time complexity is **O(nlog(logn))** , because that is the total number of iterations of innermost(while) loop.